# Mysql remote connections

Tags: mysql, server

I've an application on windows forms that needs to connect to a remote server with a static ip, however I already installed mysql on the server, provided the next command

```
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and also put an exception in Windows Firewall, but I'm still unable to connect, I don't know if there is something else to do!, I forgot to say it is a Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: do you have your keys set up?

Comment: take a look in the my.xnf to the bind parameter. it is possible that the server only listen on 127.0.0.1. so you cant reach them from external. if so, change it to 0.0.0.0 and restart the db server

Comment: Apparently a shutdown of the server and a new admin user was needed to be created, after that everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue with previliges of user. This is about connection rights. LIke mostly on CPanel we have an option of Remote MySQL. Under this option we either have to provide ip address which we want to allow to connect to mysql or wild card mask % to allow any ip to connect to the server. Check with your hosting how it allows you to connnect. yes these previliges are necessary thay you have given. that is ok but check Remote MySQl if you have cPanel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs and trap your errors.

- Confirm your app can reach the sql port and connect.  (From the windows machine, can you telnet to the sql port on the sql server?)  If not, look at your firewall, and verify your sql instance is bound to a public ip as Bernd suggests.
- Once you know the host can reach the sql server, verify your app is actually connecting. Trap errors from connect functions and read them out.
- Then verify the credentials are accepted.  Again, trap any errors and read them out in your program.
- Then, when you're processing a sql statement, trap any errors and read them out to yourself in your program.

(You may find it useful to write a log file from your program containing any errors you detect on any line of code interacting with your database)

Once you've narrowed down where your issue actually is, a solution will probably present itself.  Or at least you'll have narrowed it down, and can update us with a specific error message from where the failure has occured.

Good luck!

Comment: Used telnet however I got the message with a lot of giberish gotpacketsoutoforder, and I can connect using
        mysql -h localhost -u root -p